Using UseContext and ContextProvider in React App
I want to use UseContext hook in my react app that's some simple shop app,that has landing page and a shop.I want to share cart info in all of my components,I've been followign the guide how to do this but it doesn't work (I get the default value which is null)
CartProvider.jsx
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const CartContext = createContext(null);

const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  const addToCart = (item) => {
    setCart([...cart, item]);
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{ cart, addToCart }}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
const useCart = () => {
  const context = useContext(CartContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useCart must be used within a CartProvider");
  }
  return context;
};
export { CartProvider, useCart };

My app structure:
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <CartProvider>
        <NavBar />
        <main>
          <div className="main-header">
            <h1 className="main-header">
              Browse our richest and fanciest collections on Shooppy!
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="button-section">
            <h2> Explore our offers now!</h2>

            <Link to="/shop">Online shop</Link>
          </div>
        </main>
      </CartProvider>
    </>
  );
}

I want to acces it in navbar for example:
export function NavBar() {
  const { cart } = useCart();

  return (
//...
   (

and I get the default value null which causes the error.
Also will,this works even when I'm using React Router?

The code should work as is (see https://playcode.io/2181324). The error lies somewhere else. Check how you export/import your components.

If you are not providing any value in the <CartProvider> like this <CartProvider value={defaultValue}>, then it will take the value which was initially set i.e. const CartContext = createContext(null). Also it works even if you're using React Router. Hope this answers your query.

But they are passing a value.

To access the context in NavBar component, you should deconstruct the context.
First you should export the context itself from the CartProvider.jsx:
export const CartContext = createContext(null)

or
export { CartProvider, useCart, CartContext }

then use it in the NavBar:
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { CartContext } from 'CartProvider'

export function NavBar() {
  const { cart } = useContext(CartContext)

  return (
      //...
  )
}


They are using the useCart hook that they export.


(I get the default value which is null)

In fact your code has been well set.
Please check your code as below. The console logs shows the value of cart as an empty array which is what you have assigned as its default value. Therefore your code works fine as it has been coded.
export function NavBar() {
  const { cart, addToCart } = useCart();
  console.log('cart');  // cart
  console.log(cart);    // []
  return 'Testing NavBar';
}

Now to add items, you need to invoke the handler addToCart. Once it has been invoked, item will add into the cart state. Please see below some code does the same on test basis.
On clicking the button Add test items, test items will be added to cart. One item will add on every single click.
export function NavBar() {
  const { cart, addToCart } = useCart();
  console.log('cart');
  console.log(cart);
  return (
    <>
      {' '}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          addToCart('item #' + new Date().getMilliseconds());
        }}
      >
        Add test Items
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

Test run
Please see the logs once I have clicked this button three times.
// cart
// ['item #956']

// cart
// ['item #956', 'item #757']

// cart
// ['item #956', 'item #757', 'item #183']

Once the items have been added as below, you can refer to cart as below.
export function NavBar() {
  const { cart, addToCart } = useCart();
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {cart.map((item) => (
          <li key={item}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>{' '}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          addToCart('item #' + new Date().getMilliseconds());
        }}
      >
        Add a test Item
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

Test run: After adding four items, the same items have been displayed as below

